# Pass service to named Link function in custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I prefer to use named functions whenever possible. But I cant' seem to figure out how to use a named function for the link function in a custom directive.

Here's what works:

```
.directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function myDirective($log) {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    myData: '=',
    forms: '='
  },
  templateUrl: 'myDirective.template.html',
  controller: myDirectiveController,   // Not shown in this example
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  bindToController: true,
  link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {}
    $log.debug('testing');
}
```

Here's what doesn't work:

```
.directive('myDirective', myDirective);

/* @ngInject */
function myDirective($log) {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    myData: '=',
    forms: '='
  },
  templateUrl: 'myDirective.template.html',
  controller: myDirectiveController,   // Not shown in this example
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  bindToController: true,
  link: myLinkFunction
}

function myLinkFunction($scope, elem, attrs) {
  $log.debug('testing');
}
```

Passing the $log service into the named function doesn't work either:

```
function myLinkFunction($scope, elem, attrs, $log) {
  $log.debug('testing');
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It is not possible. You cannot inject anything in link function. That is what directive factory constructor is for. Just define the link function within the directive constructor, and $log should be accessible. Which is probably what you are doing but then what is meant by "Here's what doesn't work:" WHat is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how variable scopes work in JS. You can't expect that `myLinkFunction` will assume your directive as parent variable scope because `myLinkFunction` was defined outside. Also you can't inject into `link` functions or just add an additional parameter and pass it there. But the following will work

```
function myDirective($log) {
return {
  ...
  // there are 5 mandatory parameters for link
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
    return myLinkFunction(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn, $log);
  },
  ...
}

function myLinkFunction(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn, $log) {
  $log.debug('testing');
}
```

The cleaner way is to make the controller contain all the stuff that the directive needs:

```
function myDirective() {
return {
  ...
  controller: function ($log) {
    this.$log = $log;
  },
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  bindToController: true,
  link: myLinkFunction
}

function myLinkFunction($scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
  ctrl.$log.debug('testing');
}
```

Though it works best without controllerAs, it will pollute the scope otherwise. Fortunately, there are other options how nested directives talk to each other without using controllerAs.

Answer (score 0):

you can't inject the service into the link function so the 2nd approach is not valid ,, yet the first one should work correctly

did you try to use $inject ,, add this line before your function declaration

```
myDirective.$inject = ["$log"]
```

try this and tell me ,,

Comment: OP is using `@ngInject` ng-annotate will take care of it, no need for $inject. Also you need explicit annotation only for minification safety.

Comment: I know that ,, but sometimes , there are configurations to stop the automatic annotation ,, I thought you might have them ,, but I also noticed that you declare link function outside the directive scope ,, $log service is defined only inside this scope ,, you can't call it from outside

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

The link function has *set* parameters, it cannot be extracted from the DDO* and still have access to the DI'd values, as you cannot inject things into the link step.

If you want to extract it from the `return`value of the DDO you can do the following:

```
app.directive('...', function ($log) {
  function linkerFn () {
    $log('something');
  }

  return {
    link: linkerFn
  };
});
```

*: Directive Definition Object